# GridDB environment Variable Setup

Tags: linux, path, griddb

I followed [GridDB docs](https://griddb.net/en/blog/python-client/) documentation and I am now stuck at the environment variable setup. Where to find the client and python client paths. I found the path **python_client-0.8.1 ** inside swig but don't know other paths need help!

I ran this make command:

```
   $ cd ../python_client
make
```

I followed up to this point is docs
[Next up: setting our environment variables. We just need to point to the proper locations]
And next step it suggesting is setting the PATHs:

```
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:[insert path to c_client]
$ export  PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:[insert path to python_client]
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:[insert path to c_client/bin]
```

I found the python_client path inside swig now where to find others?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2slo1.png)

Answer (score 0):

the path to the c_client will be wherever you installed it. part of the python_client installation process is to also install the c_client. I normally just place it in /opt/c_client